# how to get embedded flash movie to communicate with .net winforms app

Tags: vb.net, actionscript-3

Hi I've used the shockwave flash com object to embed my flash file. I have buttons you can click on within the flash movie. Is it possible to get flash to notify my winform app which button has been pressed. It's developed using actionscript3. I'm using the latest vb.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use FSCommand, or use ExternalInterface. The later is better, although it may be harder to understand at first because of the format it uses, although if you've already solved the CallFunction (or SendFunction?) method argument, it's the same.

There are documentation and a sample C# project in Adobe's site, but I don't know the exact URL.

EDIT: To catch FSCommand and ExternalInterface calls there are two events you can subscribe to.

Also, you could also use sockets (either binary or XML).

Comment: sorry it's a working progress didn't really plan it. Which one can send from my .net app to flash then?

Comment: ExternalInterface.call to call from Flash to your container. To call Flash from the container you first need to do ExternalInterface.addCallback to register your function, and then you'll be able to call flashOcx.CallFunction (or SendFunction, don't recall the exact name=

Answer (score 0):

That's a very open question as there would be many ways to do this depending on how your website and winforms applications are setup.

My initial suggestion would be to have your flash movie call some client side javascript on the button clicks. The javascript could post to a .Net SOAP webservice for instance which logs the button interaction to an associated database. Then your winforms application could finally check the database for the presence of new button click records.

This is just one high level suggestion based on the very high level question asked. If there's more specific information available then this can be refined.

Brian.

Comment: No website is involved just an winforms app and a embedded flash file. The reason I'm flash is because flash is designed for animation. I presume it would take considable work to do animation in .net.

Comment: @Ageis: If you have no specific requirement to use Flash then I'd suggest you use Silverlight / WPF which is natively .Net and offers all the animation / styling you require.